# Use node.js-eureca.io from apache-server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On my Raspberry Pi I installed *node.js* and afterwards I tested some stuff with *eureca.io*.
Now I downloaded a little example Chat application, but it's running on Port 3000 so if I want to use it I have to enter `http://www.myRaspiIP:8000` which isn't very comfortable.

Of course I could just redirect Port 80 to 8000 within the Router but I also have an Apache-Server running on my Raspberry so that's no acceptable solution.

I thought about just placing the eureca-script in the Folder `/var/www/chat` so as to access the Chat on a normal way: `http://www.myRaspiIP/chat` - it doesn't work even if the HTML loads, the Javascript fails to connect.

In a future step I wanted to use the eureca-framework for a (only SinglePlayer yet) Javascript game on my Apache-server, but I don't know how to embed the framework if it doesn't work like I said above.

If it helps somehow, I've got my code from: [example-code](http://eureca.io/downloads/eureca.io-tchat-app-tutorial.zip) - [chat-tutorial](http://eureca.io/tchat-tutorial.html).

**Short summary:** it's everything installed properly and works on Port 8000 - I only want to find out how to run it otherwise as I searched for hours and found nothing at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some form of reverse proxy that routes requests to /chat to 127.0.0.1:8000.

Personally, I'd do it with nginx, as it's faster and easier to set up than apache. There are a lot tutorials on the net on this topic, here's one http://tltech.com/info/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: That looks really great. I'll definitely try it - but instead of redirecting Port 80 to 81 via terminal I could just use the router without having to fix this IP-problem, no?